# Windows service and Electron native windows app communication using window messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, wcf, electron

I have an windows service sending windows message such as HWND messages, i need to recieve these messages on the electron app and perform some action. How to achieve this?

The service finds a window by its name and postmessages to that window. But how does electron recieve that message?

Below is my service code

```
const int wm_app = 0x0400;
int openFile = 0x065;
IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow(IntPtr.Zero, "electron Browser window name");
PostMessage(hwnd.ToInt32(), (wm_app + openFile), 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hook to the BrowserWindow to listen for the Windows message.

```
browserWindow.hookWindowMessage(0x465, (wParam, lParam) => 
    // Your function here
})
```